# ASP.NET Core windows scheduled task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm attempting to run windows scheduler task using dotnet core 2.0.
 the problem is that I have to specify the IIS localhost port to perform the task showing in below code.

I want to perform task without using ".UseUrls("http://localhost:8089")" code.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        var pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);

        var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
           .UseUrls("http://localhost:8089")
            .UseStartup<Startup>().Build();

        host.RunAsCustomService();
    }

}
```

Comment: "I'm attempting to run windows scheduler task using dotnet core 2.0" - Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Am I understanding that you mean a "scheduled task" when you say "Windows scheduler task"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use background tasks with hosted services instead of windows scheduler. You will break the cross-platform compatibility of your asp.net core app since windows task scheduler is only available in Windows OS. You can check these articles if you're interested in hosted services: [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) & [Building a scheduled task in ASP.NET Core/Standard 2.0](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html)